# How to change the main task between two activities?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen

I'm so begineer level of Android.. so I need you guy's advice..

I have two activities

A -> MainActivity

B -> LoadingActivity

My problem is,

when I execute my application, firstly, A is started and it takes 4 seconds to do database task.. So I thought it would be better to make another activity just for showing loading page..

So in the MainActivity, I wrote this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, LoadingActivity.class));  <-- this
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

What I intended is, the LoadingActivity should be started, before this MainActivity is started, so that LoadingActivity shows the loading image on the screen for 4 seconds to cover MainActivity database task.

So, my intended sequence is,

B(show up on screen for 4sec) -> A(started almost same with B, working behind the B activity screen) -> B is killed (call finish() method)  ->  than, use the app.

please, give any advice, would be very appreciate..

And, here is my LoadingActivity class code..

```
public class LoadingActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 6000;
private String tag = "LoadingSplash";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.start_up);

   String localUrl ="file:///android_asset/loading_gif.gif";



   WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.startup);

   //wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
   //wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
   Log.i(tag, "WebView get Setting finish....");

   wv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
   wv.setInitialScale(getScale());

   //wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   //wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
   wv.loadUrl(localUrl); 

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       /*
        * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
        * want to show case your app logo / company
        */
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // This method will be executed once the timer is over
           // Start your app main activity      
           Log.i(tag, "Here is Runnable Method...");
           finish();
       }
   }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    Point p = new Point();
    display.getSize(p);
    int width = p.x;
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(800);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}
}
```

Comment: you can simply use `ProcessDialog` to show loading.

Comment: start ProgressDialog on OnStart or onCreate and dismiss  that when you finish you activity

Comment: Use AsyncTask and ProgressDialog instead of taking separate activity.

Comment: May I ask you guys favor to show me the example code..? Because I don't figure out just a short comment.. sorry.. I'm too much begineer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two separate activities, you can execute an AsyncTask thread to do your database works and in "onPreExecute" method of AsyncTask class start to show your "desired custom view"(probably containing progressBar) and do your stuff in "doInBackground" method and in "onPost" method of AsyncTask class just set that "desired custom view"'s visibility to Gone.
Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Asynctask For Background processing. After Processing complete you can start next activity.You Should use progress dialog on async task  :)

if you are not understanding then u can ask to me...

Regards
Asim